# How to install required version of pandas library in HP unix?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using HP-UX mlapp B.11.31 U ia64 139177356 a unix server and installed python 2.7.16 along with pip.
But when I am going to install  python_dateutil-2.5.3 it is showing dependency issue though SiX 1.13 is installed .

it is happening with all libraries like pandas and numpy seems like dependecy issue

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil==2.5.3) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil==2.5.3)
```

Again pip list has installed six =1.13

```
pip list
pip        19.3.1 
setuptools 42.0.1 
six        1.13.0
```

If any one having any ideas of installation of python pip  packages in HP UX kindly suggest

Note. Python 3 is not possible due to vendors issues and internet is not accessible in server due to organisation policy so, I installed using source tar file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From your error, you first need to upgrade the six package. You can do this using the following command:

```
pip install six --upgrade
```

Once you have **six>=1.5**, you should be able to install python_dateutil-2.5.3.

Btw, I would highly recommend to use **Python3.x**. Any specific reason for using Python2.7?

Comment: In HP unix python 3 is not available and not provided by vendor in our organization   . Agin six =1.13 which is greater than 1.5 so need of upgrade is really required  . Again in our server no internet access is there in server so installed only possible from tar source file

Answer (score 0):

maybe u have skipped a few steps while installing Python and related packages.

so try:

`sudo apt-get install python-dev libpq-dev`

and then `pip install` your packages.